# How to get the attribute id which is inside a td using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table id="tbl1" width="650" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0" class="normal-text">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="200" align="left" valign="top" class="singleCheckbox">
                                                        <input id="rptService_ctl01_rptSubService_ctl01_chkSubService" type="checkbox" name="rptService$ctl01$rptSubService$ctl01$chkSubService" checked="checked" /><label for="rptService_ctl01_rptSubService_ctl01_chkSubService">Energyquote Customer Agreements</label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="20" align="left" valign="middle">

                                                        <input type="hidden" name="rptService$ctl01$rptSubService$ctl01$hdnServiceid" id="rptService_ctl01_rptSubService_ctl01_hdnServiceid" value="536" />
                                                    </td>

                                                    <td width="40" align="right" valign="middle">
                                                        <select name="rptService$ctl01$rptSubService$ctl01$ddlFrequency" id="rptService_ctl01_rptSubService_ctl01_ddlFrequency">
    <option value="1">Daily</option>
    <option value="2">Weekly</option>
    <option value="3">Monthly</option>
    <option value="4">Quarterly</option>
    <option value="5">Half Yearly</option>
    <option value="6">Yearly</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="7">One Time</option>

</select>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="40" align="right" valign="middle">
                                                        <input name="rptService$ctl01$rptSubService$ctl01$txtExpireDate" type="text" id="rptService_ctl01_rptSubService_ctl01_txtExpireDate" class="from" size="8" onKeyDown="preventBackspace();" />
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="150" align="right" valign="middle">
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>

$('.normal-text td ').each(function () {
var cellText = $(this).html();                   
});
```

The above code will get all the elements which are inside a td tag. But i need to get the checkbox id and hidden field value which is inside a td tag. I tried but its not able to fetch

I have a table as above have a class as **normal-text** for this table. I had used the below code to fetch elements which are inside a td

```
$('.normal-text td ').each(function () {
var cellText = $(this).html();                   
});
```

Here am getting the whole element value which is inside a td tag but i want to get the value of checkbox id and hidden value which is inside  a td tag. Please suggest me

Answer (score 1):

This is how to get it:

```
alert("Checkbox is checked: " + $(".normal-text td").find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked'));

alert("Hidden field value: " + $(".normal-text td").find("input[type='hidden']").val());
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/txk856xy/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have multipl eor single you can write logic for that. Check the snippet

```js
var checkbox = $('.normal-text td > input[type=checkbox]');
var hidden = $('.normal-text td > input[type=hidden]');

if(checkbox.length>1){
  //if you have multiple
  checkbox.each(function(){
    console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
  });
}else {
  //if you just have one
  console.log(checkbox.val());
}


//similarly ...
hidden.each(function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl1" width="650" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0" class="normal-text">
    <tr>
        <td width="200" align="left" valign="top" class="singleCheckbox">
            <input id="rptService_ctl01_rptSubService_ctl01_chkSubService" type="checkbox" name="rptService$ctl01$rptSubService$ctl01$chkSubService" checked="checked" />
            <label for="rptService_ctl01_rptSubService_ctl01_chkSubService">Energyquote Customer Agreements</label>
        </td>
        <td width="20" align="left" valign="middle">
            <input type="hidden" name="rptService$ctl01$rptSubService$ctl01$hdnServiceid" id="rptService_ctl01_rptSubService_ctl01_hdnServiceid" value="536" />
        </td>
        <td width="40" align="right" valign="middle">
            <select name="rptService$ctl01$rptSubService$ctl01$ddlFrequency" id="rptService_ctl01_rptSubService_ctl01_ddlFrequency">
                <option value="1">Daily</option>
                <option value="2">Weekly</option>
                <option value="3">Monthly</option>
                <option value="4">Quarterly</option>
                <option value="5">Half Yearly</option>
                <option value="6">Yearly</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="7">One Time</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td width="40" align="right" valign="middle">
            <input name="rptService$ctl01$rptSubService$ctl01$txtExpireDate" type="text" id="rptService_ctl01_rptSubService_ctl01_txtExpireDate" class="from" size="8" onKeyDown="preventBackspace();" />
        </div>
    </td>
    <td width="150" align="right" valign="middle"></td>
</tr>undefined</table>
```